How to use Python virtual environments with ROS 2 building with --symlink-install flag?
I want to use a Python virtual environment with ROS 2 and build my package with colcon build --symlink-install.
I followed this simple tutorial: Running ROS2 Nodes in a Python Virtual Environment and the indication on How to use (python) virtual environments with ROS2?. Both work well, since I don't use the --symlink-install flag.
Has anyone managed to use a Python virtual environment with --symlink-install or has a clue how to do so?
